# How to apply animation only to specific views in LayoutAnimationController

Tags: android, animation

This question has already been asked before( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658416/how-to-apply-android-layout-animation-only-to-children-above-a-certain-index) ). But there is no good answer.

I want to apply animation using `LayoutAnimationController` only to only few views in the ViewGroup( The viewgroup here is a ListView). How should i do that?

```
   LayoutAnimationController lac = new LayoutAnimationController(getActivity(), AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in), 0.3f);

mYearListView.setLayoutAnimation(lac);
```

Or by any way can i apply two types of animation in a single LayoutAnimationController? For example, for views 1 to 4, animation 1  and for views 5 to 8, i want to apply animation 2?

Comment: tried overriding getAnimationForView()?

Comment: That is a final method. Cant be overriden

Comment: argh, missed that, sorry

Comment: so the easiest way would be to create some kind of custom Animation class, say it AnimationProxy which will have a list of Animations in its constructor and use one of them in applyTransformation/getTransformation

Comment: How do i access applyTransformation/getTransfromation here?

Comment: how? class AnimationProxy extends Animation {.. and override a method you want